# How can check u , v edges connect or not in DFS C++

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

**input v = 4 , e =3 

edges (1,2) 

edges (3,2) 

edges (3,1) 

i want to check u = 3 , v = 1 

out put : yes
and i want check u = 1 , v = 3 

out put : no 

have matrix 

0 1 0 0 

0 0 0 0 

1 1 0 0 

0 0 0 0**

```
void DFS(int i,int t)
{   
int j;
visited[i] = 1;

cout << i+1 << " ";

if(i == t)
    cout << "yes";
for(j=0;j<V;j++)
{   
    
    if(G[i][j]==1 && visited[j] == 0)
        DFS(j,t,x);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally a DFS implementation for something like this might look something like (I haven't tested it so there may be an issue or two):

```
bool dfs(int this_node, int destination_node) {
    // base case where this node is the destination node
    if (this_node == destination_node) return true;

    // mark this node as visited
    visited[this_node] = true;

    // go deeper in the search
    for (size_t next_node = 0; next_node < V; ++ next_node) {
        // skip the search if this node isn't a valid child
        if (visited[next_node] || !g[this_node][next_node]) {
            continue;
        }
        // here is the recursive step
        if (dfs(next_node, destination_node)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // if we made it all the way here, then the search failed to reach the destination
    return false;
}
```

Then you'd be able to call this from the main function:

```
if (dfs(source_node, destination_node)) {
    std::cout << "yes\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "no\n";
}
```

Comment: I did a lot of cases, sometimes it got a problem, the 'yes' 'no' value is mismatched.

Comment: Could you post the test cases here too in the original post? Might help with figuring out where the bug lies.

Comment: oh on i'm srroy im push main function in post you TT

Comment: which test cases are failing?

Comment: Suppose I have 12 cases. (1 2)
(1 3)
(2 1)
(2 3)
(3 1)
(3 2)
(1 4)
(2 4)
(3 4)
(4 1)
(4 2)
(4 3)  After the first case, the value of 'Yes' is wrong.

Comment: The test case being `u = 1 , v = 3`? It seems like there is a connection there (1, 2) -> (2, 4) -> (4, 3) so it should print yes - unless I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: case s  = 1 , t  = 3 shoud print "no" and case s = 3  , t =  1 shoud print "yes"

Comment: If doing one case, the value is straight, if doing multiple cases, the distortion value

Comment: Hmmm, I must not be following then - normally with a graph with multiple edges like that you have to trace through the multiple intermediate vertices to find if two vertices are connected rather than just checking the edge pairs.

Comment: How i should do continue?

Comment: If you use the edges in the example does that produce the correct results? i.e. (1, 2) (3, 2) (3, 1) should produce yes, no